# Issue about spring and spring boot properties file. I cannot pass properties as well as I want from one application in springBoot to another in spring

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have found a couple topics about it, but there aren't as specific as my problem is.

I have two applications called "platform" and the second one use this platform because it has the common specification for the entire implemented platform. Well this second one is called application.

Platform is using spring and application is using spring-boot. This is a part of my xml config file

```
 <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:*.properties" />

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.cache"/>
```

And this is my class config part

```
 @PropertySource(value = "file:${APP_HOME}/**/*.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
    //@PropertySource(value = "file:([a-zA-Z]:)?(\\\\\\\\[a-zA-Z0-9_.properties]+)+\\\\\\\\?", ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
    //@PropertySource(value = "classpath:file.properties"),
    @PropertySource(value = "file:E:/myPath/application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
    @PropertySource(value = "file:classpath:application.properties",ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
    @PropertySource(value = "classpath:../application.properties",ignoreResourceNotFound = true),
    @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
```

and I put into the platform some default value into the property file.

The problem is when I'm trying to set this value from the application I cannot do it.

There are the scenarios

When I set in my application de value, its change well and the application set it well. If I don’t put this value, my platform will set the default value from the platform's config file. The problem is when I comment this line

```
@PropertySource(value = "file:E:/myPath/application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

The application works in this way

If I set the value in my application it works fine, If I don’t set the value in my application it fails because the placeHolder is empty.

Could you help me please?? I appreciate your help

So my question is: how can i change the hardCode value?? Because with this line my application is working fine. I have tried different ways for placeHolders but it doesn't work. Please help me.

Kind regards

Comment: Placeholders don't work in `@PropertySource`s. Well placeholders work patterns don't work.